# Converting variables in Unicode

Tags: c++, winapi, variables, unicode

I'm a Javascript developer, so go easy on me! I am trying to write just a patch of C++ to enable printing on a framework. I'm compiling with Unicode, and based on my research, that is what is messing me up.

I think this is a relatively simple thing that I'm over complicating. The application has a `std::string` that contains the current printer name. The script first checks if it is unset (if it is it utilizes `GetDefaultPrinter` which outputs a `LPTSTR`). Finally, the script takes either than `std::string` or the `LPTSTR` and converts it to a `LPCTSTR` for `CreateDC`.

Here is my code:

```
std::string PrinterName = window->getPrinter();
LPDWORD lPrinterNameLength;
LPWSTR szPrinterName;
LPCTSTR PrinterHandle;

if (PrinterName == "unset") {
    GetDefaultPrinter( szPrinterName, &lPrinterNameLength );
    PrinterHandle = szPrinterName; //Note sure the best way to convert here
} else {
    PrinterHandle = PrinterName.c_str();
}
HDC hdc = CreateDC( L"WINSPOOL\0", PrinterHandle, NULL, NULL);
```

When compiling, I only get conversions errors. Such as

> Cannot convert parameter 2 from LPDWORD * to LPDWORD (GetDefaultPrinter)

and

> Cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR' (On the PrinterHandle = PrinterName.c_str() line)

I've done quite a bit of SO research on this, but haven't come up with a concrete solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope `szPrinterName` gets memory allocated for it in the function. Oh, never mind, it doesn't. You'll want to fix that and pass in memory you own.

Comment: @chris It does - I just left it out since it isn't really in the scope of the question. :)

Comment: @hmjd Boom! One down. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way for `window->getPrinter()` to return a wide string as opposed to the narrow string it returns now? If so, there's a solution that makes more sense than conversion.

Comment: Use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @ildjarn, That's why I asked. Depending on the function, it might only ever return a narrow string, which isn't compatible with `std::wstring`.

Comment: @ildjarn Tried that initially, I get 'Cannot convert from std::string to std::basic_string'

Comment: @chris You are correct, and since it is a framework, it's hard to modify those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you're compiled for "Unicode" (wide characters strings), you can call the "ANSI" (narrow characters strings) versions of the API functions.  Windows will do the conversions for you and call the wide character version under the covers.

For example, for most Windows APIs like `CreateDC`, there isn't actually a function with that name.  Instead, there's a macro named `CreateDC` that expands to either `CreateDCA` or `CreateDCW`, which are the actual function names.  When you're compiled for "Unicode", the macros expand to the `-W` versions (which are the native ones in all modern versions of the OS.  Nothing prevents you from explicitly calling either version, regardless of whether you're compiled for Unicode.  In most cases, the `-A` version will simply convert the narrow strings to wide ones for you and then call the corresponding `-W` version.  (There are some caveats here related to creating windows, but I don't think they apply to DCs.)

```
std::string PrinterName = window->getPrinter();
if (PrinterName == "unset") {
  char szPrinterName[MAX_PATH];  // simplified for illustration
  DWORD cchPrinterNameLength = ARRAYSIZE(szPrinterName);
  GetDefaultPrinterA(szPrinterName, &cchPrinterNameLength);
  PrinterName = szPrinterName;
}

HDC hdc = CreateDCA("WINSPOOL", PrinterName.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Just recompiled this this - much better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments, the proper way is to make a `DWORD` and pass the address:

```
DWORD lpPrinterNameLength;
...
GetDefaultPrinter(..., &lpPrinterNameLength);
```

Why it's like that is so that it can use and change a number:

> On input, specifies the size, in characters, of the pszBuffer buffer. On output, receives the size, in characters, of the printer name string, including the terminating null character.

It would just take a `DWORD`, but the function changes the number in the variable passed in, so the function needs the address of the variable to change in order for those changes to reflect back to the caller.

---

Secondly, since `window->getPrinter()` returns a narrow string and you're using `UNICODE`, which makes the functions take wide strings, you should convert from the narrow string into a wide one. There are several ways to do this (such as the really easy one mentioned in ildjarn's comment), and even this one is slightly better with C++11, though the aforementioned note applies even better with that, but I'll use `MultiByteToWideChar` and C++03:

```
std::wstring narrowToWide(const std::string &narrow) {
    std::vector<wchar_t> wide;

    int length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, narrow.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    if (!length) {
        //error
    }

    wide.resize(length);
    if (!MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, narrow.c_str(), -1, &wide[0], length)) {
        //error, should probably check that the number of characters written is consistent as well
    }

    return std::wstring(wide.begin(), wide.end());
}

...

std::wstring PrinterName = narrowToWide(window->getPrinter());
//rest is same, but should be L"unset"
CreateDC( L"WINSPOOL\0", PrinterHandle, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: If the OP is using VC++ 2012 they can replace `narrowToWide` with `std::wstring_convert::from_bytes()`.

Comment: @ildjarn, I wasn't sure what exactly you meant by your comment, but I figured it would be something simple like that. That's quite useful if you know VS2012 will be in use.

Comment: Or any C++11 toolchain for that matter. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn, Oh, that wasn't a VS extension? Amazing! :)

Comment: [Indeed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) – there's even something to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16: [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16). Much easier than the old `mbstowcs`/`wcsrtombs` hassle. :-D

Comment: @ildjarn, Very much so. Those should come in really handy, thanks.

Comment: +1: Also, while everyone focused on the compiler error, `PrinterName == "unset"` was also wrong.

Comment: @JesseGood, Am I missing something? From what I pulled, it's comparing to a `std::string` so it's ok, and it's an unknown function, so that return value can't easily be proven to be something different in that case. Or were you talking about the fact that I mentioned to change it to `L"unset"` in the comment?

Comment: Nevermind, I mixed up `szPrinterName` and `PrinterName`. Thanks for pointing that out.